# 'score' value in the form always return as 0

Tags: django, django-forms, return-value

in my school project, we created a basic Django app using questionnaires and videos to calculate depression. but on the final result page questionnaire 'score' always return as 0. Why is that?
I can use the 'score' in the depression_questionnaire function, it works normally but the 'score' in the detect_emotion function always return as 0

here is my view.py

```
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import os
import numpy as np
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
# from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
from .forms import DepressionQuestionnaireForm
from .models import DepressionQuestionnaire


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('depression_questionnaire')
        else:
            messages.info("invalid credentials")
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "login.html")


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password1']
        confirmpass = request.POST['password2']

        if password == confirmpass:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Username Taken")
                return redirect('register')

            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

                user.save();
                messages.info(request, "user created")
                # print("user created")
                return render(request, "login.html")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "password not matched")
            return render(request, "register.html")
    return render(request, "register.html")


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')


def formm(request):
    return render(request, "main.html")


def demo(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")


# Load the emotion detection model
model = load_model(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'emotion.h5'))


def preprocess_video(video_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frames = []
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (48, 48))
        frames.append(frame)
    cap.release()
    frames = np.array(frames)
    frames = np.expand_dims(frames, axis=-1)
    return frames


def detect_emotion(request):
    score = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DepressionQuestionnaireForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            questionnaire = form.save()
            score = questionnaire.get_score()

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['video']:
        # Get the uploaded video from the request
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['video']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

        # Preprocess the video
        video_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
        frames = preprocess_video(video_path)

        # Make predictions using the model
        predictions = model.predict(frames)
        emotion_labels = ['Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Neutral', 'Sad', 'Surprise']
        predicted_emotions = [emotion_labels[np.argmax(predictions)]]

        # Calculate the emotion score
        emotion_scores = {'Angry': 0.2, 'Disgust': 0.1, 'Fear': 0.3, 'Happy': -0.2, 'Neutral': -0.1, 'Sad': 0.4,
                          'Surprise': -0.1}
        emotion_score = sum([emotion_scores[emotion] for emotion in predicted_emotions])

        # Add the emotion score to the questionnaire score

        return render(request, 'result.html',
                      {'emoscore': emotion_score, 'score': score, 'emotion': predicted_emotions})

    return render(request, 'main.html')


def depression_questionnaire(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DepressionQuestionnaireForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            questionnaire = form.save()
            score = questionnaire.get_score()
            return render(request, 'depression_questionnaire_result.html', {'score': score})
    else:
        form = DepressionQuestionnaireForm()
    return render(request, 'depression_questionnaire.html', {'form': form})


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models



class DepressionQuestionnaire(models.Model):
    question_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_5 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_6 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_7 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_8 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))
    question_9 = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=(
        ('not at all', 'Not at all'),
        ('several days', 'Several days'),
        ('more than half the days', 'More than half the days'),
        ('nearly every day', 'Nearly every day')
    ))

    # add more questions and possible responses as needed

    def get_score(self):
        score = 0
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_1)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_2)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_3)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_4)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_5)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_6)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_7)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_8)
        score += get_score_from_response(self.question_9)

        # add more questions as needed
        return score

def get_score_from_response(response):
        if response == 'not at all':
            return 0
        elif response == 'several days':
            return 1
        elif response == 'more than half the days':
            return 2
        elif response == 'nearly every day':
            return 3
        else:
            return None
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import DepressionQuestionnaire


class DepressionQuestionnaireForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = DepressionQuestionnaire
        fields = '__all__'
```

and reult.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Emotion Detection Result:</h1>
  <p>The predicted emotion is {{ emoscore }} and emotion is {{ emotion }} questionnaire score is {{ score }}.</p>
<a href="depression_questionnaire_view">click</a>
{% endblock %}
```

we tried some solutions in the chatgpt but it's not working.

Comment: Have you determined if the `if form.is_valid()` block in `detect_emotion` is being entered? If `get_score` is never called, `score` will be left as 0.

Comment: Yeah, the function should have a different execution path if the form isn't valid.

Comment: You have not used ```Forms``` in html as well as you have not specified method ```POST``` with that form. so in the ```request.method``` always defaults to ```GET```. An example would be: ```    <form action="{{ url_for('main.depression_questionare') }}" method="POST" id="mainForm"> ```